# CakePHP 3 doesn't submit the forgeign key fields value

Tags: cakephp

I have the following 2 tables, and the default classes generated from

```
bin/cake bake all clients
bin/cake bake all clients_address
```

When I try and add an address, setting the "client_id" to `1`, I get the following error.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'client_id' doesn't have a default value

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

SQL Query:

INSERT INTO clients_address (address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3, town, county, postcode, email, tel, contact_name, default_address) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5, :c6, :c7, :c8, :c9)
```

Is there some extra code needed to get the client_id to be submitted?

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `clients_address` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `address_line_1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `address_line_2` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `address_line_3` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `town` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `county` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `postcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `tel` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
    `contact_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `default_address` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `clients` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'First Client');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `clients_address` Table schema `client_id int(11) NOT NULL`, set. But when you insert a Address then you don't set value against client_id and client_id can't be `NULL`

### Probably solutions

1. Set `client_id` in Address insert query
2. In your table schema client_id allow `NULL` or set a default value

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that "client_id" is sent. Check with your Debug Kit bar on History, select the POST request, and then go to Sql log.

There must be a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO clients_address (
  client_id, address, modified
) 
VALUES 
  (
    61, 'my address', "123..."
  )
```

If not maybe something is wrong with your Form. 
Your query must be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO clients_address (address_line_1, ..., contact_name, CLIENT_ID, default_address)
VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5, :c6, :c7, :c8, :c9)
```

If you are adding addresses standalone (addresses controller add method), you must stipulate "client_id" manually on Form, or from a hidden field based on a parameter, with Cake bake it will make a list of Clients on Add and Edit methods.

If you are adding the address from Client Form as an association, on CakePHP docs are some good examples https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data